# select two fields from thre table with query builder in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, query-builder

i have three tables and each one has "username" and "password" fields.
i want to select all username and password fields from these three and have them in one array.

i wrote it as below:

```
$command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('email','password')
            ->from(array('mosqueculturalliablee','parent','school'))
            ->queryAll();
```

but the error say email and password field are ambiguous.

how can i write this query?

Comment: Try adding table name at front, `Eg: parent.email`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('mosqueculturalliablee.email,',
'mosqueculturalliablee.password,',
   'parent.email,','parent.password,','school.email,','school.password,')
    ->from(array('mosqueculturalliablee','parent','school'))
     ->queryAll();
```

and if you want you can use `union()` also

Comment: thanks for your reply. i try this and get syntax error : Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`email`
FROM `mosqueculturalliablee`, `parent`, `school`' at line 1

Comment: You have **username** field in every table or **email** field??

Comment: i have both of them in each table

Comment: Try adding comma after every select field. I have modified the code. hope it will work

Comment: it looks like work and no error occurred but  in action when i print the result password and email of parent and school table don't appear